# Jspdf to print slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to use JsPdf on a page where i utilize a slickgrid. I am using their HTML renderer which i understand is still in its early stages. Has anyone had any success with something like this or similar? Edit i have added HTML2Canvas cdn, just not sure how to implement it. here is my [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/5zLL5m06/)

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var doc = new jsPDF();


    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#cmd').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#entirecontent').get(0), 15, 15, {
            'width': 200,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can utilize html2canvas, then you can achieve it easily

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [380, 380]);
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
    pdf.save("screen-1.pdf");

});
```

Repo: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/

Comment: I have added html2canvas cdn to my fiddle. If possible could you demonstrate there?  https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/5zLL5m06/6/

Comment: @LeonardoTrimarchi: Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/5zLL5m06/9/light/ Hope you can take it from there. Cheers.